# Button (List) Overflow in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a page which I am currently designing. The bottom of the page has links which are in the form of buttons. The links however are overlapping.

Here are the following HTML and CSS.

HTML:

```
<ul class="links"> 

<li><a href="http://www.birminghamtheatres.com/">Theatres</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.birminghammuseums.org.uk/bmag/about">Museums</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.libraryofbirmingham.com/">Library</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.links { 

        padding-top: 1%;
        padding-bottom: 1%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content:space-around;
        list-style-type: none;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;

    }
```

Can anyone help prevent the overlapping of the buttons in the list form?!

Comment: Either I don't understand your question or you didn't ask the right question or didn't post enough code. I'm seeing any overlapping link http://jsfiddle.net/dowomentfart/3kofhvv3/

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your buttons don't overlap you could give each `li` its own id. Then in your css, since you have three elements, and the full width of a browser is 100%. You can divide 100/3 which is 33.333.
Your css might look like:

```
.idforelement1{
width: 33.333%;
}
.idforelement2{
width: 33.333%;
}
.idforelement3{
width: 33.333%;
}
```